# How to set landscape format in kartik export menu?

Tags: yii2, widget, export, export-to-pdf, kartik-v

Kartik export menu exports the data in portrait format by default. I want to make it landscape but i don't know how to make it landscape. 
Please help someone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
'exportConfig' => [
    \kartik\export\ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => [
        'pdfConfig' => [
            'orientation' => 'L',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: What's the name of that file?

Comment: Which file? This is configuration array for that widget.

Comment: Should I write that code in config/web.php file?

Comment: It's usually `ExportMenu::widget([/* here */])`

Comment: It export but not in landscape:

<?= ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'column1',
            'column2',
            'column3',
        ],
        'exportConfig' => [
            \kartik\export\ExportMenu::FORMAT_PDF => [
                'pdfConfig' => [
                    'orientation' => 'L',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]) ?>